# Spring - Load custom property file based on value from application.properties

Tags: java, spring

I have application.properties file:

```
value=a
```

Then I would like to load a property file based on that value - **a.properties** and read/use properties from that file.

I was thinking about something like this:

```
@Configuration
public class PropertiesConfiguration {

@Value("${value}")
private String value;

@Bean
public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(value + ".properties"));
    return configurer;
} }
```

but the **value** is always null for some reason. When I try to get that value e.g. in service/component then it works fine. I would like to avoid using spring profiles. Any ideas how to achieve that with latest Spring?

Comment: I may be wrong, but this sounds like an X/Y problem. If you are trying to have multiple different properties files, and be able to switch between them as a developer, perhaps Spring Profiles are what you are after. Hard to say without more info about what exact problem you are trying to solve. Here's an article you might find helpful: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

Comment: @kashishverma let's say the a.properties contains only one value country=en. So later than I would like to access it in some Component as Value("${country}")

Comment: That isn't going to work obviously due to 2 things. First the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` is the component processing the `@Value` annotations. Second there is only a single pass on loading/replacing properties, not multiple passes until all things have been resolved.

Comment: @M.Deinum any proposals how to solve it? I was thinking about that 1st part which makes sense. My workaround for now is .@Bean
    .@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "value", havingValue = "a")
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeHolderConfigurer() {
     ... // load correct property file
which works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the solutions I have come across and works fine is use of Component and PropertySource annotations.

```
@Component
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:${value}.properties")
public class CountryService implements ICountryService {

@Value("${<whatever in a.properties file>}")
private String currency;

@Override
public String getCurrency() {
    return currency;
}
}
```

where **${value}** is taken from application.properties. Then Autowire that bean whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

In the line `configurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource(value + ".properties"));` it should be `"application.properties"` since your file name is `application.properties`

Also in the properties file define it as
`value = a`
with spaces

Comment: the application.properties are placed directly in resources folder on classpath so they are loaded properly (I can read the value from a Component/Service). Spaces should play a role there.